# European painting of a man standing on a dragon with his sword drawn, who painted it/what century is it from?

Tags: europe, art

Who painted this and what century it is from?

[image]

Comment: One of the Wordsworth Classics editions of "Tales of Troy and Greece" has that as cover art http://www.ebay.com/itm/TALES-OF-TROY-AND-GREECE-Andrew-Lang-1995-Wordsworth-Classics-Paperback/330300563969

 Unfortunately, I can't find a reference as to what the painting is...

Comment: Frankly, I'm just as impressed with the guy blithely strumming the lyre during a monster attack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it! The painting is of [Perseus freeing Andromeda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseus_Rescuing_Andromeda) by Piero di Cosimo painted in 1510 or 1513.

Comment: ...in which case that isn't a dragon, but rather Cetus (or the Kraken, if you get your Greek Mythology from bad '80 movies like I do).